# Unable to mount External HDD missing NTFS and UUID

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, uuid, signature

I need some help!

The facts:

I was trying to mount a microSD card while my external HDD (Samsung M3 Portable) was plugged and sth went wrong after these mistakes at command line:

sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/mmcblk0p1 
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb && sync status=progress

I stopped it 5-10 seconds after the command

My external HDD was auto mounting as sdb1, a partition of sdb
BTW when I plug a flashdrive it is runnng well as sdb1.
But every time I plug the HDD I just can't see it!

It says that the signature is lost and that the NTFS is missing.

Please take a look at a couple of outputs of some commands:

```
fdisk -l:

root@euro-VGN-CR525E:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 88,5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 88,4 MiB, 92692480 bytes, 181040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe9d95eb8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 970500095 970498048 462,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       970502142 976771071   6268930     3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       970502144 976771071   6268928     3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

```
2) df -h

**************************************************************************
root@euro-VGN-CR525E:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,5G     0  1,5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           300M   13M  288M   5% /run
/dev/sda1       456G   19G  415G   5% /
tmpfs           1,5G  4,8M  1,5G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,5G     0  1,5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7169
/dev/loop0       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
tmpfs           300M  116K  300M   1% /run/user/1000
**************************************************************************

3) blkid

**************************************************************************
root@euro-VGN-CR525E:~# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="06d633cc-3915-4e7f-bab4-1fa589a1e571" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e9d95eb8-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="808ee427-e534-4451-91ae-4d502d0cdc9d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e9d95eb8-05"
**************************************************************************

4) fsck -n /dev/sdb

**************************************************************************
root@euro-VGN-CR525E:~# fsck -n /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
**************************************************************************

5) lsblk

**************************************************************************
root@euro-VGN-CR525E:~# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 462,8G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0     3G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  88,5M  1 loop /snap/core/7270
loop1    7:1    0  88,4M  1 loop /snap/core/7169
```

---

Is it possible to recover the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usage of `dd` (AKA "Disk Destroyer") is likely to make any data recovery impossible. Are you using Ubuntu? I so why are running as root?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Actually the data is there yet. I checked it on a windows computer running the EASEUS data recovery. But its free version allow on 500 MB data retrieve. I would like to do it on my linux that has a 500 GB harddrive that can import the data.

Well, I running as root to do a couple of tasks that asks for a root user. In fact I am not an advanced linux user.

Comment: In Ubuntu we use `sudo`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sudo_root.8.html

Comment: Probably first thing it erased was partition table. Was it one large or multiple partitions. Testdisk & if files not seen then photorec may recover some data. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover data stored on hard drive with windows with ubuntu live?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735329/is-it-possible-to-recover-data-stored-on-hard-drive-with-windows-with-ubuntu-liv)

Comment: Hi! Thank you all for helping. I'll try those instructions.